# How to change the installer's icon using Installshield 2011?

Tags: installation, icons, installshield

I'm using Installshield 2011 to create an installer and it create an output installer whose icon is something that I want to replace one of my own. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found this in the [InstallSheild 2011 evaluation guide (PDF)](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/webdocuments/PDF/evalguide_IS2011.pdf) - does this work for you?

> 1. In the View List under Media, click Releases.
> 2. In the Releases explorer, click the your release.
> 3. Click the Setup.exe tab.
> 4. In the Setup.exe Icon File setting, specify the fully qualified name of the file that contains the icon
>      that InstallShield should use when it creates the Setup.exe file at build time.
>
> [image: installshield screenshot]